# Why is it wrong to derive the chain rule this way?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

My book says that the chain rule can stated as $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dy}{dt} \dfrac{dt}{dx}$$

However, it the book says that it is incorrect to reason that the chain rule is true because the $dt$'s cancel out. Why is it incorrect? I've heard people saying that differentials are not really numbers, but I don't know what to think because my book had just finished a section where it defined $dy$ and $dx$ as $(y-\Delta y)$ and $(x-\Delta x)$ respectively, and the book even used values such as .01 to substitute in place of these differentials.

Comment: Some Calculus books publish a wrong proof as of the rule as this paper claims (and shows the correct proof): http://kruel.co/math/chainrule.pdf
of the chain rule

Comment: @EmmadKareem In which class do the professor start going into real detail about the fundamentals of calculus? I am in a calculus 3 class in and it's still not been delved into

Comment: I can't tell for sure. I guess it depends on your specialization and on the course structure. Chain Rule may be provided to students to apply only but for students with major in Math, the proof may be studied further in Real Analysis course.

Comment: Are you sure it defined $dy$ and $dx$ as $y-\Delta y$ and $x-\Delta x$? I don't see how the quantities $y-\Delta y$ or $x-\Delta x$ would be natural to consider. They don't go to zero as $\Delta x,\Delta y\to 0$ for instance. And they are definitely not the quantities in the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$. Which means you're back to square one of not knowing any literal interpretation of the $dy$ and $dx$ in the expression, which means there is no way to cancel anything, which makes the question moot. Of course, intuitively it seems like there should be cancellation, which occurs in the proof.

Comment: @NoChance I can't edit comments, but your link died.  [Here's the archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20160307021739/http://kruel.co/math/chainrule.pdf).

Comment: @JohnBaber-Lucero, thanks for the new link. If you edit your comment to so that it tells what is it for, I will remove my comment with the dead link. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentials are indeed not numbers*. Basically, they represent a change in a quantity which has "already gone to zero". Thus they really only carry meaning in a ratio, where you can have a ratio of two quantities which are both going to zero, yet the ratio can have a finite, nonzero limit.

To prove the chain rule rigorously, you should actually consider two distinct cases. First you should assume $f$ is differentiable at $g(x)$, $g$ is differentiable at $x$, and $g'(x) \neq 0$. Then you can do something which actually looks like the "cancellation of differentials". Specifically you can write:

$$\frac{f(g(x+h))-f(g(x))}{h}=\frac{f(g(x+h))-f(g(x))}{g(x+h)-g(x)} \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}.$$

Now you split into two limits and send $h \to 0$. Because of the additional assumption that $g'(x) \neq 0$, we can actually compute the limit of the first factor, and everything turns out to be OK. (It is not completely automatic, but it is quite doable.)

Second you should separately should prove that if instead $g'(x)=0$, then $(f \circ g)'(x)=0$.

What your book is doing in these problems where differentials are replaced by small finite numbers is approximate. Specifically, part of the point of the derivative is that $\Delta y \approx \frac{dy}{dx} \Delta x$ provided $\Delta x$ is sufficiently small. But this is approximate: we do not have anything like "$dy=\Delta y$". And indeed, we should use "$\approx$" not "$=$", in these problems.

* There are ways to properly handle these infinitesimal quantities as separate entities. Collectively these ways are called *nonstandard analysis*. For various reasons, none of these approaches are popular.

Comment: Right, I was thinking that differentials only make sense in quotients, but Ive had some brief exposure to differential equations and it seems that differentials are outside of quotients very often. I think I even saw differentials by themselves, not multiplying another function or anything.

Comment: @Ovi The most common place this is done in differential equations is "separation of variables", where you formally turn an equation of the form $\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x) g(y)$ into $\frac{dy}{g(y)}=\frac{dx}{f(x)}$ and then integrate both sides. But this is "really" integration by substitution: you really have $\int  \frac{1}{g(y)} \frac{dy}{dx} dx = \int f(x) dx$. Then you can integrate by substitution, which is in turn justified using the chain rule for derivatives and the FTC. This can be done even more carefully by doing all the integrals as definite integrals.

Comment: @Ovi (Cont.) The other main place is in "exact equations", where you have an equation of the form $M(x,y) dx + N(x,y) dy = 0$, with a certain relationship between $M$ and $N$. Yet again, what is going on can be made precise without this form: you can have $M(x,y) + N(x,y) \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$. It is equivalent to say that the vector $[M,N]^T$ is perpendicular to the vector $[1,dy/dx]^T$. But the latter is the tangent vector of a certain curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Thus $[M,N]^T$ is the *gradient* of a function whose level set is the curve.

Comment: @Ovi (Cont.) And this is how we solve exact equations: by finding a function whose gradient is some given conservative vector field.

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle problem with the given answer. In

$\frac{f(g(x+h))-f(g(x))}{h}=\frac{f(g(x+h))-f(g(x))}{g(x+h)-g(x)} \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h},\ $ the conclusion that

$\frac{f(g(x+h))-f(g(x))}{g(x+h)-g(x)}\rightarrow f'(g(x))$ as $h\rightarrow 0$ is not automatic.

Even if $g'(x)\neq 0$, the proof is not trivial because by definition

$f'(g(x))=\lim _{k\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(g(x)+k)-f(g(x))}{k}$ and this is not the same thing as $\lim _{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(g(x+h))-f(g(x))}{g(x+h)-g(x)}$.

To do this properly, it's a little more fussy. See this easy to follow [proof](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DerivativeProofs.aspx#Extras_DerPf_ChainRule).

Comment: Eh...it's not automatic, but it is not too difficult. In particular I think it is essentially trivial once you prove that $g$ is monotone in a neighborhood of $x$. Thus it is invertible, which you can exploit to good effect.

Comment: But if you prefer, you can avoid division altogether: $f(g(x+h))=f(g(x)+g(x+h)-g(x))$. Linearly approximate the change in $f$: $f(g(x+h))=f(g(x))+f'(g(x))(g(x+h)-g(x))+o((g(x+h)-g(x))$. Now linearly approximate the change in $g$ and simplify a bit: $f(g(x+h))=(g(x))+f'(g(x))g'(x)+o(h)$. That gives the result smoothly. But it requires some decent understanding of the subject already to really understand what this is doing.

Comment: @Ian: agreed.  But it does need proof, because the limits are not a priori the same. Using the definition (without splitting the quotient into two factors) is not too difficult and it also provides a template for the chain rule in higher dmensions. I just saw you did exactly that! Nice.

Comment: @Ian I do not understand how it is trivivial if we prove g is monotone in x